# SSH proxying 'kit' available?

Tags: windows, ssh, socks-proxy

Is there a software package for Windows or Mac that kind of packs up the logic of using an SSH host as a dynamic SOCKS forwarder (e.g. `ssh -D 1080 yourhost`) into a nice looking GUI? I'm imagining something that presents a username and password prompt, then internally forks putty or OpenSSH. Better yet, it could frob the system proxy settings to use the forwarded SOCKS port, and then unfrob them when the program exits.

I'm considering writing it if not.

Answer (score 1):

Give **Putty Connection Manager** a try, it might give you the 'wizbang' you seek:

[image: Putty Connection Manager]

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/03/putty-extreme-makeover-using-putty-connection-manager/

**Download here:**

http://sourceforge.net/projects/puttycm/

Comment: This is nice, but still not what I am looking for. (Especially with the .NET dependency.) I am pretty convinced it doesn't exist. I guess I will have to write it myself.